# Read last line of a large file with NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I'm using [this example](https://coderwall.com/p/ohjerg/read-large-text-files-in-nodejs) to read a large file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require('stream');

var instream = fs.createReadStream('your/file');
var outstream = new stream;
var rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

rl.on('line', function(line) {
  // process line here
});

rl.on('close', function() {
  // do something on finish here
});
```

And I want to know when `line` is the last line of file. I read the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) but can not find a solution. I already tried:

```
rl.on('line', function(line) {
    if (line == '' || line == require("os").EOL)
        console.log('eof');        
});
```

but it didnt work.
Do you have any suggestions. Thanks for reading.

Comment: A quick look at the documentation make me wonder if the solution is to use [`moveCursor`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_movecursor_stream_dx_dy) as much as possible.

Answer (score 10):

The problem with Axel's answer is he assumes the last line of a file will be empty or an EOL. This is not the case.

```
// fileTools.js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const Stream = require('stream');

exports.getLastLine = (fileName, minLength) => {
    let inStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
    let outStream = new Stream;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        let rl = readline.createInterface(inStream, outStream);

        let lastLine = '';
        rl.on('line', function (line) {
            if (line.length >= minLength) {
                lastLine = line;
            }
        });

        rl.on('error', reject)

        rl.on('close', function () {
            resolve(lastLine)
        });
    })
}
```

To use:

```
const getLastLine = require('./fileTools.js').getLastLine
const fileName = 'C:\\someWinDir\\somelog.log'
const minLineLength = 1
getLastLine(fileName, 1)
    .then((lastLine)=> {
        console.log(lastLine)
    })
    .catch((err)=> {
        console.error(err)
    })
```

Comment: I have been meaning to learn how to write promises, you sir just taught me how. +1

Comment: just wondering from performance side, is reading all lines the right way?

Comment: Depends on many factors. However...
https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1691:_Optimization

Comment: Can it be rewritten to `async/await`? Wait, replace the ugly `then` with `await` and put it in a `async` function. Maybe you edit your code to improve it.

Answer (score 7):

I used `exec(tail -n 1 <filepath>)` in my mocha test suite because I know exactly what it does and it does it with fewer lines of code...

Perhaps its a little less optimal when building an application though

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
exec("tail -n 1 nginx_access.log",  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   console.log(stdout)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Save the line you receive inside a global variable, then display it once you reach the end of the file.

```
var lastLine = '';
rl.on('line', function(line) {
    if (line == '' || line == require("os").EOL) {
        console.log('eof, last line is', lastLine);
        return;
    }

    lastLine = line;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the condition has never been true

Comment: Let's print the content of each line with a debugger or `console.log(line);` then find out why.

Comment: There is the definition of `rl` missing, it is probably `readline`
?

Answer (score 5):

To read last N lines of a large file efficiently, we can use this npm package `read-last-lines`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-last-lines

Example reading last 50 lines of a file :

```
const readLastLines = require('read-last-lines');
readLastLines.read('path/to/file', 50)
    .then((lines) => console.log(lines));
```

Comment: Note: Max line # value specified does not include trailing empty new line (but does include empty lines before it), and the `lines` parameter here is just a string on which you need to call `lines.trim().split('\n')` to get an array.

Answer (score 3):

Save the current line, and when you get to the end of the file you have the last line. The input stream emits an "end" event when all of its data is consumed. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require('stream');

var instream = fs.createReadStream('your/file');
var outstream = new stream;
var rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

var currentLine;

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    currentLine = line;

    // process line here
});

instream.on('end', function() {
    // currentLine is now the last line
    // use currentLine here
});
```

You could alternatively use the `rl.on('end')` event, but that emits for a few more reasons, like an interrupt or calling `rl.close()`, but those might not affect you.
https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close

Comment: Please improve your answer by not using mystery variables, (just copy the relevant lines from the op's code to make a complete answer).

Comment: this is quite inefficient way of getting the correct line, you're basically going through all the lines and re-declaring the variable over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a dependency for https://github.com/alexbbt/read-last-lines and as a consequence to `mz/fs`, seemed like a lot to me for one function.

Also the code of `read-last-lines` seems a bit dated.
I took the code of `read-last-lines` and just refactored it a bit. All credit goes to `read-last-lines`.

The following code basically reads a file character by character from back to front and counts how many line breaks it encountered.

I did not test if this is actually faster than streaming through all lines of a huge CSV file.

```
import * as fs from "fs";

const NEW_LINE_CHARACTERS = ["\n"];

async function readPreviousChar(
    stat: fs.Stats,
    file: number,
    currentCharacterCount: number,
    encoding: BufferEncoding = "utf-8"
): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.read(
            file,
            Buffer.alloc(1),
            0,
            1,
            stat.size - 1 - currentCharacterCount,
            (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(buffer.toString(encoding));
                }
            }
        );
    });
}

/**
 * Read in the last `n` lines of a file
 * @param  {string}   inputFilePath   - file (direct or relative path to file.)
 * @param  {int}      maxLineCount    - max number of lines to read in.
 * @param  {encoding} encoding        - specifies the character encoding to be used, or 'buffer'. defaults to 'utf8'.
 *
 * @return {promise}  a promise resolved with the lines or rejected with an error.
 */
export async function readLastLines(
    inputFilePath: string,
    maxLineCount: number,
    encoding: BufferEncoding = "utf-8"
): Promise<string> {
    if (!fs.existsSync(inputFilePath)) throw new Error(`File ${inputFilePath} does not exist.`);

    const [stat, file] = await Promise.all([
        new Promise<fs.Stats>((resolve, reject) =>
            // Load file Stats.
            fs.stat(inputFilePath, (err, stat) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(stat);
                }
            })
        ),
        new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) =>
            // Open file for reading.
            fs.open(inputFilePath, "r", (err, file) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(file);
                }
            })
        ),
    ]);

    let chars = 0;
    let lineCount = 0;
    let lines = "";

    while (lines.length < stat.size && lineCount < maxLineCount) {
        const nextCharacter = await readPreviousChar(stat, file, chars, encoding);

        lines = nextCharacter + lines;
        if (NEW_LINE_CHARACTERS.includes(nextCharacter) && lines.length > 1) {
            lineCount++;
        }
        chars++;

        if (lines.length > stat.size) {
            lines = lines.substring(lines.length - stat.size);
        }
    }

    if (NEW_LINE_CHARACTERS.includes(lines.substring(0, 1))) {
        lines = lines.substring(1);
    }

    fs.closeSync(file);

    return lines;
}
```